# How to plot (1+x)(1+y)>=20?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python, I want to plot this region.

```
(1+x)*(1+y) >= 20
```

I do not know how to do it in `matplotlib`. I search on the Internet and found `fillplots` package but I do not understand how to use it for two variables.

This is an example in fillplots:

```
from fillplots import plot_regions
plotter = plot_regions([
    [(lambda x: x ** 2,),  # x ^ 2 > 0 and
     (lambda x: x + 5,)],  # x + 5 > 0
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fillplots import plot_regions

plotter = plot_regions([
    [(lambda x: 20.0/(1.0+x) - 1.0,),
    ],
])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Basically, you express is as `y=f(x)` and either ask to fill region where `y<0` or where `y>0`

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. I like the plot from Severin but the math can't be right. If y is -1, then the statement evaluates to 0 and cannot be >= 20. Should the lower left quadrant (and upper right) be shaded, not the middle? I think this relates to negative * negative and how the equation was transformed.

Edit: I gave a shot to editing the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532229/4938264). I think this is close to what is being asked for. The vertical line is the boundary (not actually shaded) and could be edited using techniques [here](http://fillplots.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#simple-example-simple-py).

```
from fillplots import plot_regions

plotter = plot_regions([

    # positive y+1 values (require positive x+1)
    # plotted in blue in this image
    [(lambda x: 20.0/(1.0+x) - 1.0,),        # False (default) means y > equation
     (-1,)                                   # and y > -1
    ],

    # y < -1 returns a negative value for (y+1) and requires
    # (x+1) to also have a negative value
    # plotted in green in this image
    [(lambda x: 20.0/(1.0+x) - 1.0, True),   # True means y < equation 
     (-1, True)                              # and y < -1
    ],

], xlim=(-40,40), ylim=(-40, 40))

plt.show()
```

[image: fillplots positive and negative fills]

Comment: bumped reputation as much as I can

Comment: Thanks... I tried an answer to have a more substantive contribution! It relied on your code. Great to learn about the fillplots library.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it only works in terms of one variable. If you want to plot

```
(1+x)*(1+y) >= 20
```

you will have to convert it to

```
1 + y >= 20 / (1 + x)

y >= 20 / (1 + x) - 1
```

as Severin has done.